# Can't detect the bottom side of my rectangle UI object

Tags: c#

I am trying to detect all sides of a rectangle UI object for a bounding detection program I am writing. Now, it detects top and left sides of the rectangle easy enough but it passes through a detection line, bottom side first, it does not register it! Here is an illustration of my problem:

[image]

This is how I am checking for the (bottom) side:

```
double bottom = currentY + item.Height;

if (myBottom >= detectionLine[i].Position)
{
  MessageBox.Show("Bottom");
}
```

Can anyone help me figure out what my is wrong with my logic? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: `myBottom >= detectionLine[i].Position` will return true if `myBottom` and `detectionLine[i].Position` are both numeric, and the former is greater than or equal to the latter. Until you tell us what their respective values are, nobody can tell you more than that.

Comment: Were you confused with `bottom` and `myBottom`?